# Where to find an Acta Mathematica latex package?

Tags: journal

I contacted the journal but they still don't answer me.

If answering first question is difficult:

What it the commonly used police of this Sweden journal?

What other official presentation forms of this journal?

Comment: I don't believe they have a standard package.  They just ask for manuscripts written in latex or tex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web page http://www.actamathematica.org/publications/acta-mathematica/submission-manuscripts indicates that you should submit a manuscript in LaTeX first, not using any special package for their journal, and then wait for acceptance. After acceptance, they will then give suitable instructions for their LaTeX requirements as changes to the LaTeX file.

Comment: This same procedure should be followed for all mathematics journals that I can think of, even if they might say otherwise: they all seem to referee papers in any LaTeX format, and accept or reject before they require use of any special package.

Comment: agreed that established journals referee submissions before acceptance (or rejection, but think positively).  one practice that will minimize problems when modifying an accepted file for publication is to *not* enlarge the width of the page to allow more space for wide displays.  stick as close to the text width of the published journal as possible.  your enlarged pages cannot be accommodated by a journal with a narrower format, and the editorial adjustments necessary to make material fit may well introduce errors.  avoid the problem up front.

Comment: @magox: I don't see any sign from their web pages to indicate that they require a letter of recommendation for non-students or non-affiliates. How did you find out that they have such a requirement? If you need help finding a suitable journal, you might ask someone who carries out research in the field of mathematics that your paper is most closely related to.

Comment: because I sent them the real riemann hypothesis confirmation and they missed the chance... saying “we need a recommandation...”